# Putting a hashtag twitter feed in a UIScrollView for iPhone (Objective C)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, twitter, uiscrollview

I've got a UIScrollView which I'd like to put a twitter feed into (the feed is for a hashtag), but I can't work out how to parse the XML, I'm relatively new to XCode so I could do with a bit of hand-holding or a thorough description on how to do this.

Someone on another thread advised about something called TouchXML but I can't even find TouchXML.

Can anyone help? (The sooner, the better, preferably)

Answer (score 0):

Your `UIScrollView` could be a `UITableView` and then you should be able to download and parse the XML file and use it as a datasource.

Regarding XML, you have many options. I always refer to [Ray Wenderlich's great article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) that has a very nice comparison among different alternatives.

Be sure to understand everything regarding tables, the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) is the place to start.

BTW, TouchXML is [here](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help, do I have to use a TableView or is a Scrollview acceptable? The thing is, I'm trying to make a semi-transparent scrolling area which just shows plain text (would be happy with white text and a bold white name as a parse).

Comment: Also, do you know how to download the XML file? (and where I get it from)?

Comment: No, you don't have to use a table view, but I think it would simplify things a lot for you. And if you want to check about downloading the XML file, there are many samples out there - or check the ASIHTTPRequest library.